# Selecting "NA" value from 1st dropdown should not disabled "NA" value from 2nd dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Here i'm preventing multiple selections of Same Value. Even NA value is disabled 
how to prevent NA value being disabled?

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/g62r51x3/)

Html code:

```
<label>1st dropdown</label>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="NA">NA</option>
</select>
<br />
<hr/>
<label>2nd dropdown</label>
<select id="select2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="NA">NA</option>
</select>
```

Js code:

```
 $("select").change(function()
     {
     $("select option").attr("disabled",""); //enable everything
        //collect the values from selected;
         var  arr = $.map
         (
            $("select option:selected"), function(n)
             {
                  return n.value;
              }
          );

     $("select option").filter(function()
        {

            return $.inArray($(this).val(),arr)>-1;
         }).attr("disabled","disabled");   

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
return ($.inArray($(this).val(),arr)>-1 && $(this).val() !== 'NA');
```

in your `filter` function.

Comment: @SVK did it help ?